# Blogdown and links on social sharing buttons

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I am new to hugo and blogdown and am creating an academic website using hugo-academic theme.

Everything works great. Except the social sharing buttons. When I run blogdown::build_site(), the social sharing buttons on blog posts don't seem to have full urls and therefore will fail.
see. 
e.g. https://nkaza.github.io/post/urban-morphology-landscape-metrics/

The url variable is "/post/..." rather than "baseurl/post/...".

If, on the other hand, I run hugo in the terminal, I get the right urls for the sharing buttons for the same config file. However, the Rmarkdown posts disappear. This seems like a strange behaviour.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to fix the urls?

If interested, the website sources are at https://github.com/nkaza/website
and the published version is at https://nkaza.github.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange! your code works on my machine by using either `blogdown::build_site()` or `hugo`

Here is a piece of the generated html, url looks fine:

```
<li>
  <a class="twitter"
     href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Using%20Blogdown%20and%20Github&amp;url=https%3a%2f%2fnkaza.github.io%2fpost%2fusing-blogdown%2f"
     target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

You might be using an old hugo, try to update it by `blogdown::update_hugo()`

And..

> If, on the other hand, I run hugo in the terminal, I get the right urls for the sharing buttons for the same config file. However, the Rmarkdown posts disappear. This seems like a strange behaviour.

This is because they are `drafts`, to render drafts , use

```
hugo -D
```

Comment: Thank you. That is indeed strange. I suppose I should have mentioned the versions. Blogdown version is 0.6.13 and hugo version is 0.42.2 on my machine.  However, hugo -D seems to have fixed the problem on my end.